# How to change content of first Child dynamic

Tags: javascript, css, grid

```
for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
let childDiv = document.createElement('div');
  divi.id = "addDay";

childDiv.className = "boxName";
divi.appendChild(childDiv);
childDiv.textContent = "0"; 
}
document.querySelector('#map'); 
map.appendChild(divi);
divi.firstChild.style.backgroundColor = "green";
change();
}
function change(){ 
n = document.getElementById('addDay');
n.firstChild.textContent = 'something'; 
}
```

I need to change content of first child of addDay on every click,but this function makes it only once. What do you think where is problem?

Comment: Where is the opening curly-braces for `change();}`? Edit the block if there are typos, please.

Comment: Can u see it again,please?

Comment: How about this: `object.onchange = function change(){...};` or `object.addEventListener("change", ...);`